# Configure Static IP For bridge connection

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, ethernet, static-ip, bridge

I am working on Raspberry pi 3B+ (Having Ethernet and wlan both).

Currently i am trying to create a bridge connection between my Ethernet port and tap which i am using for other purpose.

Below settings works fine if i want to have dhcp conenction.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
#allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp   
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

#iface default inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
#   address 192.168.0.120
#   netmask 255.255.255.0
#   network 192.168.0.0
#   broadcast 192.168.0.255
#   gateway 192.168.0.1
#   dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
    pre-up ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
    pre-up brctl addbr br0
    pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0
    pre-up brctl addif br0 tap0
#   pre-up ip link set eth0 up
    pre-up ip link set tap0 up
#   post-down ip link set eth0 down
    post-down ip link set tap0 down
    post-down ip link set br0 down
    post-down brctl delif br0 eth0
    post-down brctl delif br0 tap0
    post-down brctl delbr br0
    post-down ip link del tap0
    bridge_ports eth0 tap0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

What i want to achieve is to have static IP address for bridge connection or Ethernet connection.

**Note:** If i change in above code as static ip for br0 connection then it does take static ip. But now i am not able to connect (ping) to wlan or ethernet or bridge connection. But i do able to ping to (raspberrypi.local)

sample for static code

## bridge

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.120
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
    pre-up ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
    pre-up brctl addbr br0
    pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0
    pre-up brctl addif br0 tap0
#   pre-up ip link set eth0 up
    pre-up ip link set tap0 up
#   post-down ip link set eth0 down
    post-down ip link set tap0 down
    post-down ip link set br0 down
    post-down brctl delif br0 eth0
    post-down brctl delif br0 tap0
    post-down brctl delbr br0
    post-down ip link del tap0
    bridge_ports eth0 tap0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: Which DHCP server programme are you using?

Comment: Why do you need a static IP address?

Comment: @LegendusMaximus I need static IP address as whomsoever connect to pi they able to ping or connect via same ip address.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Is it Raspbian Buster? Raspbian prefers to use **dhcpcd** as networking system and old style Debian **ifupdown** isn't used and you have to take care to configure dhcpcd to coexist with ifupdown. Did you respect it?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify that you want the PI to be given a static IP address via the router admin page if you have access to that.

Comment: No i will be not having access of it.